# In postgresql, Copying data of a column from table1 to table2 which is of different datatype in table1 and table2

Tags: postgresql

Text datatype of a column in table1 has to be converted to integer datatype in table2 while copying the data. That is 3 categories are there in a column of table1 which has to be converted to integer type like(1, 2,3) in table2

Answer (score 0):

Frist create select sql command from table 1 with the casting column and then create insert statement like this

```
insert into table2 (categories) select categories ::integer from table1
```

if you have more then 1 comunm then

```
insert into table2 (categories,column1) select categories ::integer,column1 from table1
```